# Can't import win32crypt

Tags: python

This is the error i get and it's says unresolved import.

```
import ctypes, smtplib, os, win32crypt, time, urllib, requests, queue
```

Error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32crypt: The specified module can not be found.
```

I have tried `pip install pypiwin32`and `pip install pywin32` but it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from win32 import win32crypt
```

solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for you

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: try pip3 install pypiwin32