# Unable to import win32crypt, pywin32, pypiwin32, win32 or win32api

Tags: python, google-chrome, winapi, encryption, pywin32

I am trying to decrypt passwords for my google chrome.  I am on the device the passwords were set up on, and logged in to the user the passwords were set up on.  This is the code I am using:

```
import os
import sqlite3 
import win32crypt
def get_chrome():
    data_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + r'{path/to/login-data}'
    c = sqlite3.connect(data_path)
    cursor = c.cursor()
    select_statment = 'SELECT origin_url, username_value, password_value FROM Logins'
    cursor.execute(select_statment)
    login_data = cursor.fetchall()
    cred = {}
    string = ''
    for url, user_name, pwd in login_data:
        pwd = win32crypt.CrypyUnprotectData(pwd)
        cred[url] = (user_name, pwd[1].decode('utf8'))
        string += '\n[+] URL:%s USERNAME:%s PASSWORD:%\n' % (url,user_name,pwd[1]. decode('utf8'))
        print(string)
if __name__=='__main__':
    get_chrome()
```

I have tried many suggestions in similiar posts, such as importing from win32 ([Can't import win32crypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119328/cant-import-win32crypt)), which I also tried changing to pywin32, pypiwin32 and win32api, none of which worked, all giving me the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxx'" error.  I've verified that I have pywin32 and pypiwin32 libraries, both up to date.  Nothing seems to let me import win32crypt.  I haven't found an article that has worked for me yet.  How can I import win32crypt, or decrypt these passwords in a different manner?

I have located the win32crypt file in the win32 library and have also confirmed pywin32 and pypiwin32 both exist.
[pywin32 and pypiwin32 exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Abz.png)
[win32crypt.pyd exists in win32 lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u89m.png)

Comment: *OS*, *Python* version, and some output proving that you have the installed libraries. Also *pypiwin32* is crap.

Comment: OS: Win10, Python Version: 3.8.  Unfortunately, I'm not as my work PC, so I don't have the pip list to prove that I have those libraries, but I can confirm I have both pywin32 and pypiwin32, and from what I'm lead to believe, those should contain win32crypt, right?

Comment: updated to include proof that libraries exist, yet I still cannot call any of the above-mentioned packages.

Comment: Are you sure you start the same *Python* (as the one you shown the images from)?

Comment: I did confirm that too, it is definitely the correct one and the only one I use.